# How to converted a string into four numbers in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, hex, decimals

I want to have a string that can be converted into four numbers.

For example, it converts a string from E17B1237 into (225, 123, 18, 55), this is converted from hexadecimal into decimal.

```
E1 => 225,
7B => 123, 
12 => 18, 
37 => 55,
```

How can I do it? hexadecimal into decimal is just an example, is there any way to do that?

How do I distinguish a string E17B1237, split into (225, 123, 18, 55), then do the conversion. Thanks.

Because I want to have a rectangle in the coordinate, and use x, y, w, h to create a unique ID, then I can also use the unique ID to retrieve x, y, w, h.

How do I create a unique ID(x,y,w,h) that can be clear to split into four numbers, then do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of conversion is rather expensive in terms of gas. I'd suggest alternate methods to implement the same logic.

Your unique identifier could be the `keccak256()` of the coordinates. An example implementation could look like this.

```js
mapping (bytes32 => uint8[]) hashToCoordinates;

function getCoordinates(bytes32 hash) public view returns(uint8[] memory){
    return hashToCoordinates[hash]
}

function addCoordinates(uint8[] crds) public returns(bytes32){
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(crds));
    hashToCoordinates[hash] = crds;
    return hash
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really nice solution.

Comment: Because I want to use the ID to be tokenID in ERC721, can I just convert like this? uint256 tokenID = uint256(hash);

Comment: Yup. That's a good way to do it too.